# Removing only certain special characters in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove certain special characters. I haven't found a method for addressing such and most require stripping the entire text and then writing back to a new/same file. (-that I've found!)

```
•Consistent
```

I need the bullet point removed but not dollar signs or pretty much any other special character.

I get to this point by

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(myList,columns=['filename','text'])
df.to_csv("./SECParse.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig', sep=',',index=False)
```

Is there any way to add to the *df.to_csv* line that eliminates only bullet points?

Comment: Try `df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace('•','')`

Comment: Thank you! You solved my issue! Appreciate it -